# How to filter according to id

Tags: python, django

I want to filter states data accroding to countryId. in my models.py is

```
 class Country(models.Model):
    country_id=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    country=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country

 class State(models.Model):
    state_id=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    state=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    countryid=models.ForeignKey(Country,default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.state.encode('utf8')
```

i want to get the list os those states whose countryId is equal to variable which is passes in url my views.py

```
class StateViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=State.objects.all()
    serializer_class=StateSerializers
    def list(self, request,*args):
        count_id=request.GET.get("id")
        data=State.objects.all()
        serializer=StateSerializers(data,many=True)
        state_data=State.objects.filter(countryid__country_id=count_id)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

My filter is not working count_id is vaiable which i passing in url.i want those states who belong that country which have dountry id=count_id

Comment: you say "not working"; what do you mean by that? Is it throwing an error? Returning an empty queryset?

Comment: It returning all data of states

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Without knowing the exact details of how your program is "not working", I can't say for sure what's wrong, but I do see one issue.</s>
edit: Knowing now that your code is returning all states rather than the filtered list, I think I see the problem. Look closely at your code:

```
data=State.objects.all()
serializer=StateSerializers(data,many=True)
state_data=State.objects.filter(countryid__country_id=count_id)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

You initialize `data` as all States, then create a serializer from that data. You then create a filtered queryset of your States, and finally return a response formed from *the first set of data*.

In other words, you're never actually using your filtered queryset.

Does the following work?

```
state_data = State.objects.filter(countryid__country_id=count_id)
serializer = StateSerializers(state_data, many=True)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: It throw an error no such column city_country.country_id      here city is app name

Comment: A database error or a Django error? In other words, is the problem that your model is wrong or that your database does not accurately reflect your model?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
state_data=State.objects.filter(countryId__countryId=count_id)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `queryset=State.objects.get(id=count_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
state_data=State.objects.filter(countryId__countryId=count_id)
```

By the way, you should really work on your field names, `countryId` in model `State` should be `country` because otherwise it's the same field name as `countryId` in `Country` model. Also python class fields should be lower case with underscores, so you might need `country_id` to improve your code style.